# Problems with my TextView in custom view

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

Now before anyone says anything I know this kinda thing has been asked before and I've looked at alot of questions on here and haven't been able to find anything that has helped

In my custom view, I am trying to find a textview in my layout file which keeps returning null.

Heres my code:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.game );
    }
.....
```

CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends SurfaceView
{
    TextView MyTextView; // <-- THIS SHOULD BE SET    

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

Game.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gamelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.025">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/MyTextView" // This needs to be found
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/health"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/health"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <package.CustomView
                ....... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you associate your GameView with an XML file that contains a TextView with that ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set the `id` of your `TextView` within your layout file to `TextView1` all you'll need to do is assign it like this:

`MyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);`

But you'll either need to [`addView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) or inflate the Layout within your custom view.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the cast. Will add it in a moment.

Comment: That doesn't work, comes back with NULL exception. Remember am trying to find it in GameView and not Main.

Answer (score 0):

Just having a reference to a view inside a view group does not add it to the view hierarchy. You need to call addView (or one of its associated methods) - the view will then be included in the list of children views, and will then be part of the onMeasure, onLayout process etc.

findViewById recursively goes through the view hierarchy looking for the id, so the view needs to be in your view groups list of children to be found